# Can I get to know which of the email ids in my list is registered on Facebook

Tags: facebook, email

Is it possible for me to know which of the email ids in my list is registered on Facebook?If yes, can you please tell me how?

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? If not, start reading from here: http://developers.facebook.com

Comment: There are so many things to read there at http://developers.facebook.com/. I have gone through many already and searched a lot on google. Can you please tell me if this is possible or not?

Comment: But all of them should authorize first. See, the graph API can give you the email of the user that has authorized to the app. It can NOT tell you that a particular email id is registered on facebook or not.

Comment: But I can always get to know if an email id exists in FB database manually. By entering the email id only and leaving PW field blank. It returns a different error message in the cases when email id is correct or incorrect. I want to do the same programatically. Please let me know how can that be possible.

Comment: But that's not really a standard way of doing right? So, there isnt any API that facebook provides for the same

Comment: yes you are right that it is not a standard way. But i wanted to create application where you can enter any email id to get to know if the email id is registered on fb or not. Any alternative way in your knowledge if facebook does not provide api for the same?

Comment: I dont think you can do anything for this!